# Getting the last executed command as output without using up arrow - PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm looking for a command to get the last executed command as output. So far I found the automatic variable `$$`, but it gives only the last word of the last executed command. I'd like to avoid to use the up arrow of the keyboard (I need a command, not a key).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Get-History | select -last 1 | select -expand commandline`

Answer (score 4):

If the last command was part of your current session (vs. the last command at the end of your previous session), you can use the [`Get-History`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-history?view=powershell-7.1#example-4--display-the-most-recent-command) cmdlet:

```
Get-History -Count 1
```

To get just the text of the command, you can pipe it through `Select-Object`:

```
Get-History -Count 1 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty CommandLine
```

Comment: Hello @DanielSmith your answer it's very good

Comment: Hum, I thought `-count` takes X from beginning, not from end. Had no time to run stupid `update-help` on this PC.

Answer (score 0):

There is a commandlet for that, `Invoke-History`.